# Python 3: Make a list of odd numbers without iteration

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

My Computer Science teacher assigned us a problem: We have to make a list of the first 100 odd numbers, without using iteration.
I am completely stuck.

Comment: answer = [1, 3, 5, 7, ...].  Writing this sort of thing out once out teaches the benefit of looping constructs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `range` to generate your list for you:

```
first_hundred_odd = list(range(1, 200, 2))  # get an iterator in 1..200 range with step of 2
```

You don't need to turn it into a list on Python 2.x.

**UPDATE**:

Yes, turning the `range()` iterator into a `list` essentially performs iteration to fill the list, but that's at the language-implementation level - you're not iterating anything with `range()`:

```
def first_odd(num):
    return list(range(1, num * 2, 2))
```

.

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             15 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            3 (3 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

No jumps there. No jumps == no iteration.

Comment: It does, internally - the developer is not using iteration which is the given task. Using `range()` on Python 2.x straight-out spews a list and nobody would consider that 'iteration' despite internally using the same principle.

Comment: @Uriel - would you be kind to point at the opt codes that show iteration in the above code? A `while` loop is the very definition of iteration...

Comment: I can't believe that I have to cite basic Programming 101 definitions on SO: _Iteration, in the context of computer programming, is a process wherein a set of instructions or structures are repeated in a sequence a specified number of times or until a condition is met._. You cannot have iterations without jumps, not on a classic computer hardware that is. And if you're going to argue that abstracted away iterations are considered as iterations at the application level, then `2 * 2` is an iteration... Have it your way, I'm not here neither to argue nor to teach.

Comment: I don't see jump in `2 * 2` but you're claiming that abstracted-away iterations count. From a Python dev's perspective `2 * 2` is as much as iteration as `list(range(10))` is - it's not, despite both iterating over a set of instructions (at the CPU level and machine instruction level respectively). As for `citing`, _mea culpa_, I meant quoting, and Techopedia is as good source as any - pick up any programming textbook and you'll get very similar definition, I'd cite you one but I'm not in the habit of keeping textbooks around and I got my CS degree a loooong time ago. Either way, over and out.

Comment: I am not here to argue and though I disagree, you seem to be occupied by the urge to be declared right. Congrats, you earned my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
>>> list(range(200))[1::2]
```

Comment: No reason to generate the whole 200-element list just to slice it afterwards, let `range()` do your bidding.

Comment: @zwer yes, you're right, this is indeed less efective than your way!